# Is product of two Darboux functions Darboux?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know that sum of two Darboux functions need not be a Darboux function and square of a Darboux function is a Darboux function. But I have no idea what happens to the product of two Darboux functions. Can anyone please suggest anything?

Comment: What do you call a Darboux function precisely? I think it’s not too difficult to construct two functions $f,g$ mapping every interval to $\mathbb{R}$ but such that $fg$ is valued in $\{0,1\}$. Or just consider $(f+1)(f-1)$ where $f$ is Darboux and $f^2$ isn’t.

Comment: I don't know the answer off-hand and don't have time to look into it now, but other than recent research (which your question certainly isn't), the place to look up something like this is: Andrew Michael Bruckner and Jack Gary Ceder, [*Darboux continuity*](https://eudml.org/doc/146526;jsessionid=98522A06CD68A44763F32C1354F068AB), **Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung** 67 (1965), 93-117.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave Renfro points out there was a good deal of activity on the subject of Darboux functions in the past.   Jack Ceder and Andy Bruckner at  UCSB investigated such questions and produced very readable surveys on the subject.  The literature is quite large.

The *earliest* answer to your question might be this that I have lifted from a Math Review of a paper:

"It is well known that the sum (and the product) of a continuous function and a Darboux function need not be Darboux in general [Th. Radakovič, Monatsh. Math. 38 (1931), 117–122; Zbl 1, 329]."

**T. Radakovič, Über Darbouxsche und stetige Funktionen, Monatsh. Math. Phys. 38 (1931), 117–122.**

The paper related to the quote is  the article below.  If you call such a Darboux function "bad" then you will appreciate their investigation of a "universally bad" one.

**Kirchheim, Bernd; Natkaniec, Tomasz.
On universally bad Darboux functions.
Real Anal. Exchange 16 (1990/91), no. 2, 481–486.**